# Knife Rackspace - unable to bootstrap

Tags: chef-infra, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to bootstrap a Windows server using Knife Rackspace (from Windows Workstation)using the following command

```
knife rackspace server create -r 'role[TestWebRole]' --server-name BootstrapTest --node-name BootstrapTest --image 26fec9f2-2fb5-4e5e-a19f-0d12540ec639 --flavor 3 -VV
```

I can see that the servers is created but on Bootstrap knife hangs at

```
Waiting for sshdDEBUG: Bootstrap IP Address
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems quite obvious to me. You are bootstrapping a Windows client. Knife starts the node on rackspace and starts waiting for ssh daemon to start on the client. As the client is Windows - it does not have any sshd running and cannot accept incoming ssh connections.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to update your knife-rackspace to the latest (0.7.0) , they have added a new winrm bootstrap option

```
$gem update knife-rackspace
```

Command to create server using winrm instead of default ssh

```
knife rackspace server create -r 'role[TestWebRole]' --server-name BootstrapTest --node-name BootstrapTest --image 26fec9f2-2fb5-4e5e-a19f-0d12540ec639 --flavor 3 -VV --bootstrap-protocol winrm
```

You may also need to use `--server-create-timeout <seconds>` option as I have seen the windows kicks take some time

Found two things that are needed to make this work
1) if you dont specify this option the batch files for chef-client will try and run bash commands

```
 --distro windows-chef-client-msi
```

2) You have to clone from a box that has winrm pre-configured or it will fail to connect

Comment: Now it says waiting for win-rm.  Any suggestions?